# Migrate urls from Category/?EntityID=nodeid to Category/nodeid

Tags: 7, path-aliases, .htaccess

i am migrating the articles from an old site that has url's in the 
example.com/Economy/?EntityID=000018c5-8ded-4518-8690-4985cf051a4c format to drupal.

I have managed to get the Economy [field_category] part and the 000018c5-8ded-4518-8690-4985cf051a4c [article_id] into fields for each article, 
so i want to make a redirect from the old
[field_category]/?EntityID=[article_id] url scheme to a drupal friendly
[field_category]/[article_id]

I have tried creating aliases with Pathauto, but it does not work because the ? and the = are replaced with %3F and %3D

What is the best way to do that?

Regards